# Can't access my website /admin

Tags: mysql, web, admin

Whenever I go to my website's address /admin this comes up

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'hotstepp_ocart25'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/hotstepp/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7

Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/hotstepp/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10

Warning: mysql_errno() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/hotstepp/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: trace in /home/hotstepp/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: trace in /home/hotstepp/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: sql in /home/hotstepp/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: <br />Error No: <br /> Error in: <b></b> line <b></b><br />' in /home/hotstepp/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /home/hotstepp/public_html/system/library/db.php(9): DB\MySQLi->__construct('localhost', 'hotstepp_ocart2...', 'S(D!79r0HP', 'hotstepp_ocart2...', '3306') #1 /home/hotstepp/public_html/system/framework.php(25): DB->__construct('mysqli', 'localhost', 'hotstepp_ocart2...', 'S(D!79r0HP', 'hotstepp_ocart2...', '3306') #2 /home/hotstepp/public_html/index.php(22): require_once('/home/hotstepp/...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/hotstepp/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
```

How do I fix it ?

Thanks

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, You have two different MySQL passwords - one for public users (possibly - granted SELECT, maybe INSERT to some comment table or smth) and another for admin part. And the password for admin site is wrong. Check configuration, try changing password. Can try public configuration's password, but use this only for testing connection - if rights granted correctly, admin panel can stop working.

Comment: Or, which is more likely: DB username is wrong.
Try removing dots after db username - hostepp_ocart2...
 If you have ssh access to server, try if password/username is ok with:
mysql -uhotstepp_ocart2 -pS(D!79r0HP

Comment: There are no dots after username - hotstepp_ocart25

Comment: ok, maybe that's just from debug trace information - parameters are trimmed and 3 dots are added. Still, look for db login information - username, password, db name. Try logging in with those creditentials locally from server terminal (ssh).